# Difference between declaring instances of structs or classes at the end of declaration or in main?

Tags: c++, class, struct, instance

What is the difference between declaring like guy or like cow? Does declaring at the end of the struct change the scope of the instance? Is one of these considered better practice? If so, why?

```
#include <iostream>

struct person{
    int age;
} guy;

struct animal{
    int age;
};

int main(){
    animal cow;
    cow.age = 10;

    guy.age  = 20;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the scope of `guy` is global, but the scope of `cow` is local to `main()`. It's generally considered good practice to avoid global variables when you don't need them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both *scope* and *storage duration* are affected.

Scope:

- `cow` has got local scope inside `main`, and is not visible from global scope.
- `guy` has got global scope and is therefore also visible from nested scopes (such as that inside `main`).

Storage duration:

- `cow` is an object with *automatic storage duration.* It's lifetime starts at its definition (`animal cow;`) and ends when it goes out of scope (in this case, when `main` returns).
- `guy` has got *static storage duration.* It's lifetime starts when the program runs (even before `main` is entered) and lasts until the program ends.

Global variables are generaly considered poor practice. Variables should have as narrow scope as possible - this makes it easier to reason about whats happening with them and limits mistakes.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I thought it would be but I could not find an answer that was concise and definitive.

Comment: You can control global scope problems by declaring (and defining) them as pointers (pointing to nullptr initially) and only allocating/deallocating them from the heap when needed.

Answer (score 2):

You've declared `guy` as a global variable.  It is "alive" for the life of the program and is available to any part of the program at any time (though, if something is in a different translation unit, it would need to have an `extern` for it).

You've declared `cow` in the scope of `main`.  Without passing it to a function that takes a parameter for an `animal` (in some form - pointer, reference, copy), it is only accessible in `main`.  However, since `main` is the entry point for the program, it is also "alive" for the whole life of the program.  You can see the order of cleanup by providing a destructor for both that prints something to the screen when it is destroyed.

[Example](http://ideone.com/0ETOKm)

Answer (score 0):

Declared like this `gui` is a global variable, which might be considered bad practice.

In my opinion declaring variables along with the class/struct definition is mostly useful for class members, like this:

```
class Foo {
    struct data_t { 
        int x, y;
    } data;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct person {
    int age;
} guy;
```

is the same as

```
struct person {
    int age;
};
person guy;
```

In this case, the only difference between guy and cow is that guy is global and cow is local. `guy` can be accessed by any method, whereas `cow` is only active from the start of main to the end.